# Custom Master Page Ribbon does not push down content

Tags: 2013, master-page, ribbon, custom-masterpage

In my custom master page, I want the ribbon to push down the content. Since it doesn't push the content down, it will be hard to edit some properties since the ribbon will simply be upon some input fields.

I don't have the `id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-titlerowhidetitle"` so nothing is hidden (which is what I want).

Why doesn't ribbon push down content, isn't that default behavior?
Below is the snapshot of my custom master page:

[image: Screenshot with and without ribbon]

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: @DanielZiga Added a screenshot first without ribbon, and then with ribbon in a document library - edit properties.

Answer (score 0):

On one of my custom masterpage this fixed the issue:

```
#s4-titlerow
{
   display: block;
}
```

You could also try with `display: block !Important;` if the above does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
     FixRibbonAndPageLayout();
 });
```

This fixed the issue for me.